# Installing plugins and updates in Wordpress with Heroku

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I have been working with wordpress-heroku and I have been a little surprised to find out that you can't either update or install plugins directly in the server.

The method that has been suggested is that the upgrades and installs be made locally and then commited to the repositoy. But I find this process incredible tedious and annoying.

First I have to have a webserver installed. Luckily I have PHP5.4 installed and I can use the built in webserver

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then I have to connected, but it told me I need the Postgresql extension of PHP... so I installed it

**Then** it is telling me:

> Connecting to your PostgreSQL database without a password is considered insecure. 
>   If you want to do it anyway, please set "PG4WP_INSECURE" to true in your "db.php" file.

So I have to add a

```
define( 'PG4WP_INSECURE', true);
```

to the configuration and now it tells me that it can't find the database (of course) and I realize that I need to build a mock up database everytime I want to update my plugins.

All this seems really overkill. Is there a better way to work this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Heroku is another name for problem (in case of running wordpress).
Man you dont exactly need to create a whole environment locally.
Instead you can simply download the newly updated plugin from the wordpress site
put it into your local repository of the Heroku installation.
Then just git add and commit and push.
No overkills :)

If you want to test the new plugin locally
then make a separate folder in htdocs or www locally
and make a full local working mockup of the live site

no need to sync this mock coz it is just for testing the new themes and plugins.